# Cannot install library using gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

This is my build file. I'm using Intellij CE. I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/sstrickx/yahoofinance-api) yahoo finance api:

```
group 'com.scrap'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.yahoofinance-api', name: 'YahooFinanceAPI', version: '4.0.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

When I manually sync the project in the Gradle tool window, I get a red line under the yahoofinance library and a message that says

```
unable to resolve com.yahoofinance-api:YahooFinanceAPI:4.0.0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The latest version of your library is 3.5.0 http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.yahoofinance-api%22

Comment: Still cannot find project. intellij is not finding any of the classes.

Comment: add `apply plugin: 'idea'`. Use the plugin to generate an idea project. Import that project to idea and see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`4.0` YahooFinanceAPI does not exist in Maven. The latest one is `3.5.0` - cf - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.yahoofinance-api/YahooFinanceAPI

Tested by modify the version and adding an option for creating a fat jar

```
group 'com.scrap'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.yahoofinance-api', name: 'YahooFinanceAPI', version: '3.5.0' //Changed version
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

// Added new section
jar {
    from {
        (configurations.runtime).collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes("Main-Class": "Main" )
    }
}
```

Ran `gradle clean build` and the dependencies download

```
$ gradle clean build
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/yahoofinance-api/YahooFinanceAPI/3.5.0/YahooFinanceAPI-3.5.0.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/yahoofinance-api/YahooFinanceAPI/3.5.0/YahooFinanceAPI-3.5.0.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.2/joda-time-2.2.jar
:clean
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 10.199 secs
```